# How I can install Emerald on 12.10?

Tags: emerald

How I can install Emerald on Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually compile it from the last sources I found, since I wasn't able to find any deb with a newer version of it.

First, you need to install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool libwnck1.0-cil-dev libwnck-dev intltool libdecoration0-dev
```

Download the package:

http://cgit.compiz.org/fusion/decorators/emerald/snapshot/emerald-0.9.5.tar.gz

Uncompress it and compile with these commands:

```
cd emerald-0.9.5

./autogen.sh && make clean && make distclean && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/emerald
```

To run it, simply execute:

```
emerald --replace
```

If it works, you can set this last command in the "Window Decorations" section in compiz configuration with ccsm.

Comment: Hi darent thxs so much but. install dependencies done, download emerald 0.9.5 done but with the command:    ./autogen.sh && make clean && make distclean && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install.                                      appears me:    bash ./autogen.sh permission denied....what can I do

Comment: Maybe you need to make the files executable... I don't remember having this problem but you can try, in the directory where the files are, chmod +x * and repeat the process from where it's stuck. Good luck!